# angular $translate.instant returns object instead of string

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, angular-translate

Im using `"angular-translate": "^2.15.1"` with `$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sce')`

Inside my controller, I need to pass a translated string value to the $http service.

But below code is returning me `TrustedValueHolderType` object instead of a string.

`defaultMessage = translate.instant('welcome-message.default.message');`

[image]

Bare minimum plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/ZPtixjNub9kIExiuGIkp?p=preview
Open console (clear all). Then click on DE or EN button and see the log

Comment: can you create a plunker reproducing this?

Comment: @tanmay plunker, please click on DE or EN and open the console to see the log: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZPtixjNub9kIExiuGIkp?p=preview

Comment: dont know how But, `decodeURIComponent()` fixes the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as mentioned in the comment, `decodeURIComponent` might solve it. But here's what is causing this in the first place:

```
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sce')
```

this encodes your output for `$translate` globally.. which is why you could get it worked out using `decodeURIComponent`.

Maybe you could use a different strategy. The [`angular-translate` guide](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/19_security) seems to suggest `escape` strategy for this.

Here's a [**forked plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/oocBjUEosvDuiWHyWbhP?p=preview) that works with `escape` strategy and without needing to use `decodeURIComponent`